package gets invalidated
I have a misunderstanding related to invalidating a spec package.
I create 2 package spec.
create or replace package pkg_1
as
 function f_1 return number;
end;

create or replace package pkg_2
as
    v number := pkg_1.f_1;
end;

When checking, both of them are valid.
select object_name,
       status, object_type
  from user_objects
 where object_type = 'PACKAGE'
   and object_name in ('PKG_1', 'PKG_2');


Then, I define a procedure, P_1, in package spec of package pkg_1
create or replace package pkg_1
as
    function f_1 return number;
    procedure p_1;
end;

... and I check again the status of both packages
select object_name,
       status, object_type
  from user_objects
 where object_type = 'PACKAGE'
   and object_name in ('PKG_1', 'PKG_2');

... and both of them are valid

Then, I define 2nd procedure P_2 in package spec of package pkg_1
create or replace package pkg_1
as
    procedure p_2;
    function f_1 return number;
    procedure p_1;
end;

... and I check again the status of both packages
select object_name,
       status, object_type
  from user_objects
 where object_type = 'PACKAGE'
   and object_name in ('PKG_1', 'PKG_2');

... but this time, the package spec of PKG_2 gets invalidated.

Can anyone explain, please, why after defining 2nd procedure the package get invalidated as PKG_1 is not impacted by this?
On the other hand, if I create the PKG_1 as
create or replace package pkg_1
as
    function f_1 return number;
    procedure p_1;
    procedure p_2;
end;

instead of
create or replace package pkg_1
as
    procedure p_2;
    function f_1 return number;
    procedure p_1;
end;

Both packages are valid.
Thank you,

PCK_2 references PCK_1. Soo when you recompile PCK_1, PCK_2 will get invalid. But this is only temporary. The first time you call it it will get valid, or maybe you will get an error "existing state of packages has been...." and the second time the error will disapear.

@OracleDev: according to Fine Grained Dependency Tracking, PKG_2 should get invalid as I do not alter the function....

late edit: I added extra comment into the description.

It seems it is about something called "entry-point number" which refers to the order of the objects defined into a package spec.
*The entry-point number of a procedure or function is determined by its location in the PL/SQL package code. A procedure or function added to the end of a PL/SQL package is given a new entry-point number.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/adfns/schema-object-dependency.html#GUID-AEC8DF50-2AC2-4697-8CA9-F13108FBB810
This can be checked by
select procedure_name, subprogram_id 
from   user_procedures
where  object_name = 'PKG_1';

Best,
